# Wordpress gallery hover action

Tags: wordpress

I'm making a portfolio, and would like the gallery to consist of only boxes of solid color. Also, there will be an icon on top of it, signalizing what type of project it is (e.g print, web etc.). What I would like to happen is when you hover over one of the boxes, the solid color changes to a preview of the project, such as a picture. The icon should remain while the  mouse hovers over the box.

If this is incomprehensible because of my bad english, I made a graphic to visualize my desired action (the red square is on hover mode):

[image: The desired action:]

Could anyone please try guiding me?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a terribly difficult thing to do anymore, but it requires some skill with CSS3. There are also some Wordpress plugins available (try searching for Hover Image within the Wordpress plug-in site, for instance) and/or themes that include similar functionality that you may want to start with and then tweak to your purposes. But in the end, you basically need to look into the following CSS:

- :hover
- position:absolute
- z-index

See this discussion at [Wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/opacity-and-text-on-image-hover) for an idea of a place to begin. You don't actually need the :after tag discussed here. I made a similar thing using just the :hover attribute. The trick is to create an outer div which holds everything (including the image that you want to have appear) and then use "position: absolute" CSS with z-index to stack the items on top of each other. Use the :hover attribute to change the opacity of whichever item is on "top" of your stack to a lighter opacity which causes the underlying item to show through the top layer.

CSS might look like this:

```
.gallery1 {width: 280px; height: 178px; display: inline-block; float: left; margin: 5px}
.gallery1 img {position: absolute; z-index: 1}
.gallery1 div {position: absolute; opacity: 1; z-index: 2; height: 178px; width: 280px; text-align:center; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 178px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 14pt; background-color: rgb(255, 245, 130)}
.gallery1 div:hover {opacity: 0.3}
```

HTML would look like:

```
<div class='gallery1'>
<img src='whatever.jpg'>
<div>Text or code for icon here</div>
</div>
```

The idea is that through use of position:absolute the img is fixed in place within the gallery1 div, then through z-index it is set to a lower value than the div where the text or the icon are. The div with the icon is also position:absolute and given a higher z-index so that it stacks on top of the image, and it has a fixed height/width set to match the image size. Next it is given an opacity of 1 with a background-color, so that it covers up or hides the image. Through use of the :hover style this opacity is lowered allowing the image to show through.

Comment: The method i ended up with was to put a background: url(icon.png) no repeat center; on the image. This ensures that the image will stay in the center of the image, and is therefore more suitable for responsive websites. Also, you don't have to use z-index and all that. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Hi Baard--that addresses the icon floating on top but how did you address the need to have the preview of the project appear when the mouse hovers over it? That's what my answer was addressing. :)

Comment: I said this on my next post, might as well post it here as well. You are right that the solution i posted in the previous comment didn't solve all my problems, sorry about that. I ended up using the icon as a img tag, and then the both the color and the image as backgrounds in the CSS. Simple and responsive solution, worked out great. Thanks for the help!